# Giving higher weight to a labeling function in Snorkel

Tags: python, nlp, labeling, snorkel, semisupervised-learning

I am using snorkel to create labels for my training data. I currently have five labeling functions for the task which I have stored in a list. I am using the following code to apply the labeling function:

```
lfs = [lf_a, lf_b, lf_c, lf_d, lf_e]
applier = PandasLFApplier(lfs)
L_train = applier.apply(df_data_sample)

# Train the label model and compute the training labels
label_model = LabelModel(cardinality=2, verbose=True)
label_model.fit(L_train, n_epochs=500, log_freq=50, seed=123)
```

going into the task I want to give a higher weight to *lf_e* labeling function as I my testing shows it has a higher accuracy than others. Not being able to do that leads to outputs from other lfs dominating output from *lf_e*. And I also don't want to remove any of the functions as I reduce my coverage if I do that.

Is there a way to do that in Snorkel?

Comment: Have you found a way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately not!!!